# Why doesn't my C program for the Collatz sequence print the final value (1)?

Tags: c

I am currently making a program for the collatz sequence on C, however the last value, which is 1, is not being printed. For example, when I input 8, the outcome must be 8 4 2 1, but it only prints 8 4 2, or when I input 5, it only prints 5 16 8 4 2. What can I put inside the `while ( )` to print the complete answer? Thank you!!

```
void 
CollatzSequence(int n)
{

    int x = 1;

    do {
    x++;
        printf("%3d", n);
        if (n%2==0)
            n /= 2;
        else 
            n = 3 * n + 1;
    }
    while (  );

    printf("\n"); 
}

int 
main()
{
    int n;

    do {
        printf("Input an integer greater than 0: ");
        scanf("%d", &n);

        if (n <= 0)
            printf("Invalid input. Try again.\n");
    } while (n <= 0);

    CollatzSequence(n);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: hello! I removed the && x <= n, and more of the values appeared, however it still isnt printing the final value.

Comment: so sorry for the many inquiries @chux-ReinstateMonica , I changed my code to **do { } while ( )** and i tried putting **n != 1** and **x <= n**, however both codes do not print 1. may I ask what i can put instead?

Answer (score 0):

Code needs new loop exit condition.

Loop is done once `1` is printed.

Sample below.

```
void CollatzSequence(int n) {
  for (;;) {
    printf("%3d", n);
    if (n == 1)
      break;
    if (n % 2 == 0)
      n /= 2;
    else
      n = 3 * n + 1;
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```